# JPA calling stored procedure with argument

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, plpgsql

I have this procedure in my postgreSQL database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getItemsForCategory(categoryId integer)
  RETURNS SETOF ITEM AS $_$
DECLARE
  result ITEM;
BEGIN
  FOR result IN SELECT *
                FROM item it
                  JOIN item_category itcat ON it.id = itcat.item_id WHERE itcat.category_id = categoryId LOOP
    RETURN NEXT result;
  END LOOP;

END; $_$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

which works excellent using terminal, but I have trouble with calling it using JPA. Here is my code snippet(4 is value of argument cateforyId):

```
 transactions.begin();
 final StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("getItemsForCategory");
 storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(1,4).execute();
 final List<ItemEntity> itemEntityList = (List<ItemEntity>) storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();
 transactions.commit();
```

after running code above I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
You have attempted to set a parameter at position 1 which does not exist in this query string getItemsForCategory
```

Has anyone some idea how to set the value of argument correctly? I've also tried to set parameter using 0 instead of 1, calling setParameter with others datatypes of arguments (String,Object) but everytime I am receiving familiar kind of error like the one, which is shown there. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your parameters, before setting values.

```
spq.registerStoredProcedureParameter("categoryId", int.class, ParameterMode.IN);
```

See [this link](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#stored_procedures).

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!